# Posting an XML request using HTTP API

Tags: http-api

I'm trying to work with an API that expects an XML string in the body of the post. Additionally, the docs for the API specify:

> Please post with mime-type text/xml with the XML in the body of the post

I want to use the WordPress HTTP API to make this work, but I'm running into some problems. So far I have code like the following that seems to be failing.

```
$url = 'https://www.testurl.com';
$xml = <<<TESTED XML HERE>>>;
$response = wp_remote_post( 
    $url, 
    array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'timeout' => 45,
        'redirection' => 5,
        'httpversion' => '1.0',
        'headers' => array(
            'mime-type' => 'text/xml'
        ),
        'body' => array('xml' => $xml),
        'sslverify' => false
    )
);
```

My question is, am I properly setting the mime-type and am I sending the XML in the right place?

It's surprisingly tough to find examples of the WordPress HTTP API utilizing XML requests.

Comment: Try using a "Content-Type" header instead of "mime-type". Also, your body should probably just be the xml itself, not an array with an XML name pointing to it.

Comment: does your testurl.com expect to get the `xml=<xml>` if not then try changing `'body' => array('xml' => $xml),` to `'body' => array($xml),`

Comment: Thanks guys for your comments! I finally got it working. The API to which I was submitting is not well documented. Turns out, I had to submit the xml string with the key "postdata" and I had to include another key value pair of "postfield" => "value". Interesting stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out. The WordPress HTTP API was doing it's job; my problem was with the API I was working with. I just modified my code like:

```
$url = 'https://www.testurl.com';
$xml = <<<TESTED XML HERE>>>;
$response = wp_remote_post( 
    $url, 
    array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'timeout' => 45,
        'redirection' => 5,
        'httpversion' => '1.0',
        'headers' => array(
            'Content-Type' => 'text/xml'
        ),
        'body' => array('postdata' => $xml, 'postfield' => 'value'),
        'sslverify' => false
    )
);
```

Again...this was just a misunderstand of the API I was working with, not the HTTP API provided my WordPress.

Edit:
POST data should be supplied as an array, according to http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_API/wp_remote_post
The array will be transformed into a string like this:
key1=val1&key2=val2&...

Comment: sorry to drag up an old question, but where did you dig up the 'posdata' and 'postfield' parameters? Were those specific to your third party API?

Comment: @helgatheviking I have no memory of what this was even for; however, I believe that this was a requirement of the 3rd party API and nothing to do with WordPress.

Comment: thanks @tollmanz. i figured out my own problem, and the xml passed tends to be specific to the third party.

Comment: @helgatheviking Those are custom settings depending on the api. Core then builds the string with using `http_build_query()` (a native PHP function).

Comment: Thank you @tollmanz! This really helped! I only needed to change how the body is set. I just needed to provide the xml string I had setup.